# selecting top k column values in a row in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have below table structure

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  id1 INTEGER,

  key1 VARCHAR,
  key2 VARCHAR,
  key3 VARCHAR,
  key4 VARCHAR,
  key5 VARCHAR,

  val1 DOUBLE PRECISION,
  val2 DOUBLE PRECISION,
  val3 DOUBLE PRECISION,
  val4 DOUBLE PRECISION,
  val5 DOUBLE PRECISION
);
```

I am trying to write query to select top 3 val columns and their corresponding keys amongst given 5 key-val pairs.

something like
id1, key1, val1,  key2, val2, key3, val3.

where val1, val2 and val3 are top3 amongst all five values.

I was able to write it for top value and key like below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN val1 = GREATEST(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5) THEN key1 
WHEN val2 = .... THEN val2
.....
END AS top_key

  ,GREATEST(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5) AS top_val
FROM myTable
WHERE id1 = ?
```

but struggling to do it for top k columns !

Is there any custom function to find top k elements out of given elements ?

any other direct way to do this ?

Thanks in Anticipation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It basically makes a "temporary" table of `(key, value)` pairs for every row and then selects top three of the pairs for every row.

```
SELECT t.id, 
    (array_agg((a.k, a.v) ORDER BY a.v DESC))[1] AS kv1,
    (array_agg((a.k, a.v) ORDER BY a.v DESC))[2] AS kv2,
    (array_agg((a.k, a.v) ORDER BY a.v DESC))[3] AS kv3
FROM t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (t.k1, t.v1), (t.k2, t.v2), (t.k3, t.v3), (t.k4, t.v4), (t.k5, t.v5)) AS a(k, v)
) AS a
GROUP BY t.id
```

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6b0c5/2

Comment: This is cool ! Thanks a lot. is there any way to unpack the key value pairs  obtained in the select clause ?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to create Your custom composite type for key-value pair - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/rowtypes.html so You can refer to key and value by name.